# Twilio Functions: Record callback's TwiML response is ignored if recording ended with hangup

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm writing a Twilio Function that records a voicemail by the caller, then sends an SMS with the URL of the audio recording to a constant phone number. It works as expected when the caller ends the voicemail recording by pressing any of the `onFinishKey` keys. However, if the user ends the voicemail recording by hanging up, the code still reaches the console.log below but the text message never gets sent. I am *guessing* that the TwiML response is being ignored since the caller has hung up already. I tried having `Record`'s `action` point to a TwiML bin but TwiML bin doesn't seem to support SMS/Message commands as response to a voice call (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017437774-Combining-Voice-SMS-and-Fax-TwiML-in-the-Same-Response). I also tried having `Record`'s `action` point to a different Function that just sends the SMS but that led to same outcome when the SMS code was in the same Function.

Pseudocode:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    if (!event.RecordingUrl) {
      twiml.say('Starting to record...');
      twiml.record();
    } else {
      twiml.sms(`${event.RecordingUrl}`, {to: '+1-222-333-4444'});
      console.log('Prepared TwiML to send text message!');
    }
    callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the messages resource to send the SMS instead of TwiML.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
    
twilioClient.messages
  .create({
    body: 'Hello World',
    to: '+15555555555',
    from: '+1802123456 ',
  }).then(message =>  {
        console.log(message.sid);
        callback();
  })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
           callback("error");
    });
};
```